# Convert ArrayBuffer to Array and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multithreading

I am working with Parallel.js and Q.js to implement "Multithreading" into my application. Because I only can pass serializable objects to Parallel.js and I need to pass an ArrayBuffer I converted the ArrayBuffer to an Uint8Array as an JSON object with this `JSON.stringify(new Uint8Array(bytes))`, then in the Parallel.js I convert the JSON Object to an object, then try an Uint8Array and then to its buffer like this

```
var object = JSON.parse(data[0]);
var bytes = new Uint8Array(Object.keys(object).map(function(k) { return object[k]}));
var buffer = bytes.buffer;
```

this should usually work because Uint8Array have a prototype called `buffer` but buffer is always undefined. Object and bytes are correct, when I take a look at the prototype `buffer` of bytes I can see this message: `[Exception: TypeError: Method Uint8Array.buffer called on incompatible receiver #<Uint8Array>]` And I really dont know how I should fix this.

Does someone know a fix?